# GhostscriptRasterizer.PageCount always returns zero

Tags: c#, ghostscript.net

This problem has already been discussed here:[GhostscriptRasterizer Objects Returns 0 as PageCount value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56205425/ghostscriptrasterizer-objects-returns-0-as-pagecount-value)
But the answer to this question did not help me solve the problem.

In my case, it doesn’t help from kat to an older version of Ghostscript. 26 and 25. I always have PageCount = 0, and if the version is lower than 27, I get an error "Native Ghostscript library not found."

```
private static void PdfToPng(string inputFile, string outputFileName)
            {
                var xDpi = 100; //set the x DPI
                var yDpi = 100; //set the y DPI
                var pageNumber = 1; // the pages in a PDF document

                 using (var rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer()) //create an instance for GhostscriptRasterizer
                 {

                         rasterizer.Open(inputFile); //opens the PDF file for rasterizing

                        //set the output image(png's) complete path
                        var outputPNGPath = Path.Combine(outputFolder, string.Format("{0}_Page{1}.png", outputFileName,pageNumber));

                        //converts the PDF pages to png's 
                        var pdf2PNG = rasterizer.GetPage(xDpi, yDpi, pageNumber);

                        //save the png's
                        pdf2PNG.Save(outputPNGPath, ImageFormat.Png);

                        Console.WriteLine("Saved " + outputPNGPath);
                 }


            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was struggling with the same problem and ended up using [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/5.5.13.1) just to get the page count. Below is a snippet from the production code:

```
using (var reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile))
{
    //  as a matter of fact we need iTextSharp PdfReader (and all of iTextSharp) only to get the page count of PDF document;
    //  unfortunately GhostScript itself doesn't know how to do it
    pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
}
```

Not a perfect solution but this is exactly what solved my problem. I left that comment there to remind myself that I have to find a better way somehow but I’ve never bothered to come back because it just works fine as it is...

`PdfReader` class is defined in `iTextSharp.text.pdf` namespace.

And I'm using `Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptPngDevice` instead of `GhostscriptRasterizer` to rasterize the specific page of PDF document.

Here is my method that rasterizes the page and saves it to PNG file

```
private static void PdfToPngWithGhostscriptPngDevice(string srcFile, int pageNo, int dpiX, int dpiY, string tgtFile)
{
    GhostscriptPngDevice dev = new GhostscriptPngDevice(GhostscriptPngDeviceType.PngGray);
    dev.GraphicsAlphaBits = GhostscriptImageDeviceAlphaBits.V_4;
    dev.TextAlphaBits = GhostscriptImageDeviceAlphaBits.V_4;
    dev.ResolutionXY = new GhostscriptImageDeviceResolution(dpiX, dpiY);
    dev.InputFiles.Add(srcFile);
    dev.Pdf.FirstPage = pageNo;
    dev.Pdf.LastPage = pageNo;
    dev.CustomSwitches.Add("-dDOINTERPOLATE");
    dev.OutputPath = tgtFile;
    dev.Process();
}
```

Hope that would help...

Comment: The fact is that not only does not determine the number of pages for me, the method GetPage (xDpi, yDpi, pageNumber) works for me, when I myself specify pageNumber = 1.

Comment: I’m sorry I’m not quite sure that I fully understand you. Can you clarify – does you code line 

`var pdf2PNG = rasterizer.GetPage(xDpi, yDpi, pageNumber); `

work or not with `pageNumber == 1` ?

Comment: All right, apparently I misunderstood your initial question. I thought that you problem was that you always obtaining 0 from rasterizer.PageCount as described in the referred topic (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56205425/ghostscriptrasterizer-objects-returns-0-as-pagecount-value)
I've just checked my code and it seems that I had problems with `rasterizer.GetPage(xDpi, yDpi, pageNumber` call too.
Probably that was the reason I ended up with using `Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptPngDevice` instead of `GhostscriptRasterizer`.

Comment: I will update my answer and include there my method called `PdfToPngWithGhostscriptPngDevice` that apparently does exactly what you are trying to achieve. Hopefully that would help...

Comment: Alexander, how can I use GhostscriptPngDevice to convert a page of a pdf file into memory, i.e. without saving the resulting png file to disks, for example, getting a byte array?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to write images generated with GhostscriptPngDevice to memory stream or other in memory media. Apparently it only allows to write them do disk file.

Comment: I am saving the content to a temp, and then, I delete. So far so good...